# Django template looping for each character

Tags: python, django

I have a text file like generated from 100 Cisco switches like this:

```
['device1', 'device2', 'device3', 'device4', ....., deviec100]
```

and I want to show this information using loop in template. So I have something like this in my HTML file to loop through each device:

```
{% for x in devie_list %}
{{ x }}
{% endfor %}
```

But it is just adding a space between each character, so the result is like this:
[ ' d e v i c e 1 ' , ' d e v i c e 2 , .... ]

How can I tell Django, to loop through each item within the commas? or better say each list item.

Comment: Can you add the view function of this page?

Comment: Please show view function so we'd know your device_list implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first convert the `device_list` into a *list* data type, which you can do with any of the following methods, and then iterate on it as you wrote:

**Method 1: Using python [json module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)**

```py
import json
device_list = json.loads(device_list)
```

**Method 2: Using [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function**

```py
device_list = eval(device_list)
```

**Method 3: Using [string type methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html)**

```py
device_list = device_list.strip('[]').replace('"', '').replace(' ', '').split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `devie_list` is not a list of strings, but a string that *looks* like a list of strings.

You can use [**`ast.literal_eval(…)`** <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to evaluate this as a Python literal, and thus obtain a list of strings:

```
from ast import literal_eval

devie_list = literal_eval(devie_list)
```

and thus use the result of this in the template.

Answer (score -1):

return this in your view or under your model:

```
#Your list is a string you can turn into a list like this
device_list_as_list = device_list[1:-1].split(',')
```

Template:

```
{% for x in devie_list_as_list %}
 {{ x }}
{% endfor %}
```